# Shell Script: Mac, live update counter

Tags: shell

```
function somefunctiontesting() {
    per=0;
    for i in {1..4}; do
        val=$per;
        printf ${val/$per/$per};
        echo "%";
        sleep 1; 
        let "val++";
        per=$val;
    done
}
```

The output is:

```
0%
1%
2%
3%
```

Is it possible to have the per be replaced live? So the 0% becomes 1%
Something like:
0%->1%->2%etc...

Comment: search for answers here referencing `tput`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function somefunctiontesting() {
  per=0;
  for i in {1..4}; do
    val=$per;
    printf ${val/$per/$per};
    echo -n "%";
    sleep 1; 
    tput cr
    tput el
    let "val++";
    per=$val;
  done
}
```

(minimal changes to your code)

`echo -n` says "print this, but don't go to next line yet". `tput cr` says "go to start of the line". `tput el` says "erase to the end of the line".